# "Date" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I'm doing unpivot like this:

```
select    
--ID,
 Value
 from dbo.[staging]
 unpivot
 (
    Value
  for col in ([ Code]
  , [Date]
  ,[ Registered Name]
  ,[Entity Name]
  ,[transactions]
  ,[ PID])

 ) un
```

I'm getting error:

"Date" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Note: My staging table has date column with type datetime.

How can I reslove this error? Pl help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would include additional columns in the `unpivot`, such as the identifier.  But the solution to your problem is to use a subquery to cast the column to a `varchar()`:

```
select --ID, Value
from (select s.*, convert(varchar(255), [date], 121) as datestr
      from dbo.[staging]
     ) t
unpivot (Value for col in ([ Code], datestr, [ Registered Name], [Entity Name], [transactions], [ PID]
                          )
        ) un;
```

Comment: Getting error:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' and Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: Modified the above query. Its should be "convert(nvarchar(255),...". Thanks.